# How to access a password protected URL in android using volley library

Tags: android, api, android-volley

I am trying to do the following task:

[image]

[image]

I am planning to use JsonObjectRequest (Volley Library) in my code and extract the credentials but I am not able to understand where would the Username and Password be required in the request. This is a code snippet. If anyone can tell where I need to authenticate the Username and Password in this code snippet to fetch the JSON Object, it would be very helpful.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.wtf(response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.wtf(error.getMessage(), "utf-8");
        }
    });

queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use POST Method in volley:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
//                    here is your json object
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                volley errors
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I currently have 11 reputation. If you would upvote my question, I would be able to upvote your answer.Another Thing. The question has Json Object. Can it be retreived using StringRequest instead of JsonObjectRequest?

Comment: I found that sometimes JsomObjectRequest is not worked properly. StringRequest can be used in every condition.

Comment: What will happen if the user enters wrong username and password. How will the error be handled?

Comment: Log the string response and see what json you get on providing wrong password, username. Then you can add conditions (if/else) on json output.

Comment: I found that the URL you use gave {"error": "INVALID USER"} by putting the wrong username and password. so you can simply add if (object.has("error")){
                        String error = object.getString("error");
                    } else {
                        // your code here
                    }

Answer (score 1):

Create a jsonObject with username and password then pass this object to the `JsonObjectRequest`

Your code will be like this :

```
        JSONObject body= new JSONObject();

            body.put("username", "user");
            body.put("password", "userPassword");

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
              body, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
             @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.wtf(response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.wtf(error.getMessage(), "utf-8");
        }
    });

queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand [what is form-data](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) and how it is used:

> ### Definition and Usage
>
> The method attribute specifies how to send form-data (the form-data is sent to the page specified in the action attribute).
>
> The form-data can be sent as URL variables (with method="get") or as HTTP post transaction (with method="post").
>
> **Notes on GET**:
>
> - Appends form-data into the URL in name/value pairs
> - The length of a URL is limited (about 3000 characters)
> - Never use GET to send sensitive data! (will be visible in the URL)
> - Useful for form submissions where a user wants to bookmark the result
> - GET is better for non-secure data, like query strings in Google
>
> **Notes on POST**:
>
> - Appends form-data inside the body of the HTTP request (data is not shown in URL)
> - Has no size limitations

To pass username and password arguments as form-data you can create `StringRequest` and override it's `getParams` method to return a map of data.

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
    Request.Method.POST,
    requestUrl,
    onResultListener,
    onErrorListener) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("username", username)
            hashMap.put("password", password)
            return hashMap;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            // You can parse response here and throw exceptions when required.
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
queue.add(request)
```